# Can't print hex values (of emojis) to unicode on Mac OSX

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, hex, emoji

I'm trying to print hex values into unicode **emojis** both on OSX and GNU/Linux.

I have tried (for example) `\U1f600`, `'\U1f600'` and `"\U1f600"`, all of them works well on GNU/Linux with `echo -e` command, but in OSX it doesn't work at all, it only prints the raw hex value back. I've tried also with `printf` command but it only works on GNU/Linux too.

How can I make it work on OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install new `bash`. :)

The default bash in the OSX is archaic `3.2.57(1)-release`. It is because in the 4.0 is changed the license of `bash` from `GPL v2` to the `GPL v3` so Apple can't include it into his OS dist.

E.g. using the default `/bin/bash`

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release

$ echo -e '\U1f600'
\U1f600
$ printf "%b\n" "\U1f600"
\U1f600
```

using the bash from the [macports.org](http://macports.org)

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.12(1)-release
$ echo -e '\U1f600'

$ printf "%b\n" "\U1f600"
```

EDIT:
you can use perl:

```
perl -CO -E 'say chr 0x1f600'
#or
perl -CO -E 'say pack 'U', 0x1f600'
#or
perl -CO -E 'say "\N{U+1F600}"'
```

all prints

Edit2:

```
emo="\N{U+1F604}"
perl -CO -E "say qq{$emo}"   #use double quotes, but isn't a good practice
```

better, this will directly accept your `\u` sequences...

```
perl -CO -plE 's/\\u(\p{Hex}+)/chr(hex($1))/xieg' <<< "your string"
```

eg:

```
emo='some \U1f600 and another \U1f608 here'
perl -CO -pE 's/\\u(\p{Hex}+)/chr(hex($1))/xieg' <<< "$emo"
```

prints

```
some  and another  here
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there a way to make it work with the "archaic" version?

Comment: Okay, I'm doing `perl -CO -E 'say ' $emojified` inside the bash script but it doesn't show anything. (being $emojified a value taken from `values[0]="\N{U+1f600}"`. I think the problem relies in the need of `"`. Can u help me? I've also tried escaping `"` like so: `values[0]="\"\N{U+1f600}\""`

Comment: @Grender added some more examples

Comment: Thanks mate, `perl -CO -plE 's/\\u(\p{Hex}+)/chr(hex($1))/xieg' <<< "your string"` it's working like a charm, but it seems a bit slow.

Comment: The `\uNNNN and \UNNNNNNNN escape sequences` were [included in 4.2-alpha](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges).

Answer (score 0):

The function `chr_utf8_m` in [Greg's Wiki: Wooledge.org BashFAQ N 071](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071) works since bash 3.1

It does the utf8 encoding manually.

You better take a look there as the full script is quite long.

A simple version, so you get a hang of the functions is:

```
#!/bin/bash

chr () {
    local val
    [ "$1" -lt 256 ] || return 1
    printf -v val %o "$1"; printf "\\$val"
   # That one requires bash 3.1 or above.
   }

ord() {
    # POSIX
    LC_CTYPE=C printf %d "'$1"
}

# examples:
chr "$(ord A)"    # -> A
ord "$(chr 65)"   # -> 65
```